# Hilbert Basis Theorem Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In the standard proof of the Hilbert basis theorem, we make the inductive construction that $I_0 = 0$ and $I_{i+1} = \langle f_0, \ldots, f_i, f_{i+1} \rangle$ where $f_{i+1}$ is the polynomial in $R[X] - I_i$ of least degree, and make the claim that $f \in I_i$ iff $\text{deg}(f) \leq i$. Why is that true? This plays a central role later on when a polynomial is constructed that contradicts this assertion.

If we consider $R[X]$ as a module it is true, since addition of polynomials and  multiplication of a polynomial by an element of the coefficient ring does not change the degree. However, then we would just prove it for modules and not for rings. If $R[X]$ is a ring though, the degree can be changed by multiplication. e.g. $x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x +1 = (x+1)(x^2+x+1) \in \langle x+1, x^2+x+1 \rangle$.

Is it maybe that the basis theorem actually states that if $R$ is Noetherian, then **the module** $R[X]$ is Noetherian?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a source that you're getting this from? I think you may have misunderstood what is being claimed. The Hilbert Basis Theorem certainly does state that $R[X]$ is a Noetherian *ring* if $R$ is a Noetherian ring.

Comment: [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_TThkLBU1E&t=321s) at 11:20 it is stated that $f_{i+1} \in I_i$ is a contradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is actually that if $\deg f < \deg f_{i+1}$ then $f \in I_i$. (The opposite direction is not claimed).

This is clearly true, since when we are choosing $f_{i+1}$, if such an $f$ existed which was not in $I_i$, we would have chosen that $f$ rather than $f_{i+1}$.

Meanwhile, the point mentioned in the comments - that $f_{i+1} \in I_i$ is a contradiction - is because $f_{i+1}$ was chosen such that $f_{i+1} \notin I_i$.